# SQL Select one row over a matching row from two tables

Tags: sql

I have two tables with the same fields, but a final value that is calculated slightly differently. I need to combine the data from these two tables into one but need to prioritise one record over another when there is a match. Do you know how this might be possible?

Below is a mock up of two matching records:

```
ID  Balance     Type    CCY  Payment        Final_Balance
28  1068376.037 F - CC  GBP  78124          990252.0367
28  1068376.037 F - DD  GBP  982905         85470.08293
```

Apologies if the format comes out poorly, I'm unsure how to format table data.

I have thousands of records in these two tables but for a handful of records I have the same information in both tables. Essentially what I'm trying to get to is where there is a match I want it to select F-CC over F-DD so I end up with unique records in my final table.

Thanks

Comment: Please do not use tags that do not apply to your question. I removed the database tags as it is unclear which one you are actually using. Please add the tag of *only* the database you are actually using

Comment: Thanks I only used the recommended tags at the bottom of the question. Might be best for you to contact Stackoverflow and ask them to amend them, save contacting each individual if that's what you are spending your time doing.

Comment: @Carlos80: No. Stackoverflow suggests tags that *might* match. It cannot know what DBMS you are using. It can only suggest the most likely ones. So: which is it? MySQL? PostgreSQL? SQL Server? Oracle? ... It is important to know the DBMS in order to give an appropriate answer.

Comment: Thanks again for the advice, as mentioned above I was unaware and only used the tags at the bottom of the post. Having said that I never clicked on PostgreSQL or Oracle, so I'm not sure these were ever an option.

Comment: And also to get appropriated attention to your question. People here chose what technology they are more willing to answer a question. So, again, which database are you in? You still didn't answer. That is important because the answer may change from database to database.

Comment: What defines a *"match"*? When the `ID` matches? And when there is a match will the `Type` fields always be different?

Comment: Correct the ID's will match but its the type field that I need to prioritise over each other. So in the example above I would like one record returned being the F-CC.

Answer (score 0):

I personally use `ROW_NUMBER()` for things like this, but there may be a better solution.

You can re-run this SQL to show how the final answer is slowly built up:

```
declare @t1 table (id int)
declare @t2 table (id int, txt varchar(2))

insert into @t1 
select 1 union
select 2

insert into @t2
select 1, 'FC' union
select 1, 'FD' union
select 2, 'FC' union
select 2, 'FD'

select *, row_number() over (partition by id order by txt) as we_want_the_ones 
from @t2

select * from (
    select id, txt, row_number() over (partition by id order by txt) as we_want_the_ones 
    from @t2
) z
where we_want_the_ones = 1

select * 
from @t1 a
join (
    select * from (
        select id, txt, row_number() over (partition by id order by txt) as we_want_the_ones 
        from @t2
    ) z
    where we_want_the_ones = 1
) b on a.id = b.id
```

Answer (score 0):

My understanding of the question is that you have two tables (`A` and `B`) which have the exact same columns. You want to `UNION` these tables into one dataset, but sometimes you have rows in the two tables which "*match*" each other. In this case you only take one of the rows based on some priority.

From your example it seems that..

- **Match:** Occurs when the `ID` is the same.
- **Priority:** Is based on the `Type` column, prioritized by lower alphabetical order.

Also I'm assuming SQL Server, since that's what I prefer and you didn't say.

Hopefully all that is correct.. Now, here is how I would approach it.

I would start by performing the `UNION` of the two tables. Taking all records and not worrying about matching yet, putting them in a temp table to use later.

```
SELECT ID, Balance, Type, CCY, Payment, Final_Balance
INTO #AllRecords
FROM A
UNION
SELECT ID, Balance, Type, CCY, Payment, Final_Balance
FROM B
```

Next, I would `GROUP BY` the fields which determine a match, then use `MIN` or `MAX` to get the correct value for priority columns. By my understanding of your problem that means..

```
SELECT ID, MIN(Type) AS Type
FROM #AllRecords
GROUP BY ID
```

With that query you now have the natural key for all the records you want to display in your final result. All that is left to do is look up the rest of the columns using those keys, we can do this by using that query as a subquery.

```
SELECT ID, Balance, Type, CCY, Payment, Final_Balance
FROM #AllRecords r
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT ID, MIN(Type) AS Type
    FROM #AllRecords
    GROUP BY ID ) final ON r.ID = final.ID AND r.Type = final.Type
```

So all together the resulting query is..

```
SELECT ID, Balance, Type, CCY, Payment, Final_Balance
INTO #AllRecords
FROM A
UNION
SELECT ID, Balance, Type, CCY, Payment, Final_Balance
FROM B

SELECT ID, Balance, Type, CCY, Payment, Final_Balance
FROM #AllRecords r
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT ID, MIN(Type) AS Type
    FROM #AllRecords
    GROUP BY ID ) final ON r.ID = final.ID AND r.Type = final.Type
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, I have managed to get this working perfectly where the is a match/duplicate records. However the query is now excluding any records where there is a unique record with just F-CC or F-DD so am currently missing approx. 10,000 records from my dataset. Apologies if I did not detail this in the OP.

Comment: I believe the query will not exclude unique records. As long as they have a different ID from any other record.. Could you confirm that there is no other record in either table that has the same ID?

Comment: Ah, I have spotted it. Its coming from my UNION query. I seem to be pulling out duplicate records, one with F-CC and then a second which is blank. When I do the MIN its giving me the blank record rather than the F-CC or F-DD whichever is unique.

Comment: Did you come up with a solution? You could add a `WHERE` clause to the first query to filter out records where the type is not F-CC or F-DD. Or change the way the priority works to handle blank records.

Comment: Hi thank you for your help. I ended up creating a flag in the nested select query that pulled through all records and allowed me to filter using the MIN command.